# [BEROR]Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Distribution' doesn't match any identity in any profile

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, sdk

I have went through to the "T" Apple's documentation for this error for adding my profile to xcode. I've renewed the cert, and still having the issue. I have the latest xcode (4.2) and it's not seeing my distribution profile...anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what it was was I had the distribution certificate, but not the distribution profile from iTunes Connect.

Answer (score 1):

Check the bundle identifier string (it will be like com.abcd.def OR com.abcd.*) in info.plist. It should match the one specified in the profile.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue last time, here is how I resolve the issue.
First all, could you see your profile and certification from Organizer. 
1.Go to Organizer.
2.select device
3.Developer Profile, there you should be able to see all your developer profile
if your profile doesn't match your certificate, then there will be a warning there.
if you do see a warning there, then that's because your certification is not match the one in your provision file.  then update your certificate, then get a new provision file which is signed with your new certificate, then import your certification and provision file.

hope it can give you some help..

Answer (score 0):

You probably didn't select YOUR ID under `Build SEttings`/`Code Signing Identity`,

In xCode 4,

- Click your project name from the file browser,
- then click your project name AGAIN with the blue icon in the window that appears

you should see 2 tabs, "info" and "build settings"

click build settings

look for "CODE SIGNING"

choose "iPhone Developer: YOUR NAME (some weird alphanumeric ID)"

make sure ot select YOUR profile for BOTH debug and release.